# Как заменить элемент коллекции Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Есть задача: в существующем списке нужно пересоздать (не изменить) item при определенном условии. Я делаю так

```
data class Stopwatch(
    val id: Int,
    val startTime:Long,
    var currentMs: Long,
    var isStarted: Boolean =false,
    var isFinish: Boolean =false
)

private val stopwatches = mutableListOf<Stopwatch>()



stopwatches.withIndex().forEach {
            when {
                it.value.id == id -> {
                    stopwatches.set(it.index,Stopwatch(it.value.id, it.value.startTime,currentMs ?: it.value.currentMs, true,it.value.isFinish))
                }
                it.value.isStarted -> {
                    stopwatches.set(it.index,Stopwatch(it.value.id,  it.value.startTime,currentMs ?: it.value.currentMs, false,it.value.isFinish))
                }
                else -> {
                   it
                }
            }
        }
```

Может есть более лучший способ?

Comment: А зачем вы копируете, если у вас `currentMs` и `isStarted` это `var`?

Comment: долго объяснять, так требуется в задаче. про это я писал в заголовке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может вы вот это ищете?

```
stopwatches.replaceAll {
        when {
            it.id == id -> {
                Stopwatch(it.id, it.startTime,currentMs ?: it.currentMs, true, it.isFinish)
            }
            it.isStarted -> {
                Stopwatch(it.id,  it.startTime,currentMs ?: it.currentMs, false, it.isFinish)
            }
            else -> {
                it
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает. Я так понимаю replaceAll должен обязательно всё  заменить в коллекции. А как можно заменить только те айтемы которые попадают под два первых условия, а остальные оставить как есть?

Comment: Фактически заменяются только те, что переписываются новыми обьектами. Остальные "заменяются" на сами себя. Вы можете подсмотреть в исходниках как сделан метод `replaceAll` и сделать что-то свое по тому же принципу.